# Why did some of my point & shoot film photos come back with one third light white or orange?

Tags: film, troubleshooting, 35mm, olympus

[image][image]

I am just starting with photography. I had bought a Olympus trip 35 at a flea market for €4 euros. I used a Fujicolor C200. I had my ASA on 200 and used the automatic setting on my camera.

I took 36 pictures and only got 3 of them back which is quite upsetting because I was looking forward to get the moments that I had captured back.

Comment: Where these three in sequence?

Comment: I guess to a youngster, every film camera is an "old" camera. Me, I would consider the Olympus Trip 35 to be an old camera, and wouldn't automatically assume it to be in working order, especially if bought at a flea market. Consider a film SLR from the late 1990s or early 2000s. It might not be as cute as the Olympus, but you have a much greater chance of obtaining a camera that will provide you with satisfying results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My condolences for how your photos came out. It is always disappointing to get film back and find it in such poor condition.

You appear to have a camera issue with film advance, potential light leaks, and possibly an issue with subpar handling by the developer/printer which resulted in a failure align negatives correctly.

If you look at the top photo, on the right hand side, you can make out elements of what appears to be at least one other image, possibly two. Suggesting that the film did not advance far enough in the camera to move to clean film before the next picture was taken. As multiple photos are taken on the same area of film the final image will get brighter and more over exposed if there was much light in that part of the scene.

It is difficult to say if other issues were light leaks or overlapping exposures without knowing what the scenes really were. But several of them do look like light leaking in through seals on the back of the camera.

The final print alignment may be totally the result of the camera's poor frame-spacing, a careless oversight of the operator, or an automated computer system trying and failing to auto detect frame edges.

- It is generally a good idea to consider any camera you are not familiar with as being 'broken' rather than assuming it is working properly. Sadly many are not in great shape, and even cameras we think are working fine are at risk of suddenly failing on us.

The camera may be destined to sit on a shelf as art at this point.

If you do have to use a lab to develop your photos, strongly consider using services that provide return of the negatives if you're not already - There could be more usable images than the ones provided in the prints, but if you use a service that tosses your negatives and only returns prints/scans then you are totally at the mercy of however the tech aligned things for printing.

Comment: Which harebrained photo service doesn't return negatives, unless the whole film was unprocessable?

Comment: @rackandboneman OP did get negatives back. Part of the negatives can be seen in the last picture.

Comment: @xiota completely missed it. Well, I have some faith restored. Just a bit.

Comment: @Hueco Don't know why this answer puts so much effort into blaming the lab when the source of the problem is a broken camera purchased at a flea market.

Comment: @rackandboneman you'd be surprised. Apparently it's very common practice not to return negatives in the US. Mind-boggling

Comment: I'd be furiously surprised.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the film was exposed to light in an uncameralike manner. Either the camera is not light-tight anymore, or the film you used has been abused (unspooled and respooled anywhere outside a darkroom).

Also, this is an automatic exposure camera with a selenium cell meter. Selenium meters are known to fail or become intermittent from old age (which would cause severe overexposure), and should be assumed broken unless proven working on vintage equipment.